# How to fix the "No symbol __gcov_flush in current context" error while flushing the coverage from the image generated through bitbake

Tags: c, makefile, code-coverage, yocto, instrumentation

I am trying to generate code coverage for the yocto project modules. So added coverage flags (-g, -O0 and --coverage) in AM_CFLAGS as

"AM_CFLAGS = -std=gnu11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra **-g -O0 --coverage** -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable"

in Makefile.am file of a module.

These changes generated .gcno files while compiling the code with bitbake. So generated a yocto image out of all these modules.

Now loaded the image in testing device and ran functional test cases for that particular module.

There is a process running in the test device which is instrumented with "gcda" and I am able to check the "gcda"s in the process using strings command.

While trying to flush the coverage dump using "__gcov_flush" under gdb after attaching the process id to gdb, it throws an error "No symbol __gcov_flush in current context".

I found the issue may be due to stripping of binary and optimization so added 
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1" and DEBUG_BUILD = "1" flags in the recipe file of bitbake.

These changes disabled binary stripping but not the optimization. Please let me know,

1. How to disable in optimization in bitbake? and
2. What may be the cause for "No symbol __gcov_flush in current context" error while flushing the coverage?

Comment: Does the gcno files are included in the image? maybe try to add them with FILES_${PN} += "..somepath../*.gcno"

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nayfe.
I have added only "--coverage" flag to the Makefile and it successfully generated ".gcno" files while building the image.
I came to know that the ".gcda" info is getting stripped so want to add flags that avoid stripping of gcov data. Please let me know the flags that I can use to avoid this issue.

Comment: packages are split into `${PN}` and `${PN}-dbg`, did you add -dbg package to image? There are lots of information redarding debugging in [mega manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#debugging-with-the-gnu-project-debugger-gdb-on-the-target)